# Dropdown not working on IE 8 or 9 only

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I've got a number of product options for my products within the page provided below, on all modern browsers the drop-downs work fine including the automatic changing of price once you've changed some options which cost more etc. But on IE8 and 9, the drop-downs are not working at all, no additional options appear.

One weird workaround I realised is if I put all the javascript wrapped with the `<!-- -->` tags (as seen below) at the bottom of the page instead, the dropdowns work but the auto updating of price (again on IE8/IE9) does not work, so cant rely on just switching it around either.

There is a fair bit of code below, I didn't want to miss anything out so i've included it all, but didn't want to just seem like i'm throwing up all code and asking, here help me. This is (regarding the javascript) everything to do with those option dropdowns and the price.

Live page: http://bit.ly/1hyQzm0

HTML/Cubecart PHP Elements

```
<div id="product_detail">    
  {if $PRODUCT.ctrl_sale}
    <h1><span class="price_previous">{$PRODUCT.price}</span> <span class="price_sale" id="have_to_be_changed">{$PRODUCT.sale_price}</span></h1>
    {$final_price = $PRODUCT.sale_price}
  {else}
    <h1 id="have_to_be_changed">{$PRODUCT.price}</h1>
    {$final_price = $PRODUCT.price}
  {/if}
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    <!----------------------------------- !!! ------------------------------->

    var javascript_array = {$js_array};
    var fade_timer;
    console.log(discount_array);
    $('.lets_change_the_price').change(function(){
        var option_selected = $(this).val();
        var option_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var opt_class = $(this).attr('class');
        option_id = option_id.replace('option_', '');
        // console.log(option_selected);
        // console.log(option_id);
        var current_price = $('#have_to_be_changed').html();
        console.log ('current before = '+current_price);
        current_price = current_price.replace(currency_symbol,'');
        current_price = current_price / $('#prev_mult').val();
        current_price = current_price - $('#prev_'+option_id).val();
        // console.log ('current after = '+current_price);
        var new_price = (current_price*1) + (javascript_array[option_id][option_selected]['price'])*1;
        embro_chage = (new_price*1) - (current_price*1);

        new_price = new_price * $('#prev_mult').val();
        // console.log (new_price);
        $('#have_to_be_changed').html(currency_symbol+new_price.toFixed(2));
        $('#prev_'+option_id).val(javascript_array[option_id][option_selected]['price']);

        // font addon 
        if (option_id == 18) {
            //console.log ('we have to show picture - '+opt_class);
        }
    });

    <!----------------- --------------------------->


    $('#option_price').change(function(){
        if ($('#prev_1').val() >=0 ) {
            var prev_price_1 = $('#prev_1').val();
        } else {
            var prev_price_1 = 0;
        }
        if ($('#prev_2').val() >=0 ) {
            var prev_price_2 = $('#prev_2').val();
        } else {
            var prev_price_2 = 0;
        }           

        var normal_price = $('#have_to_be_changed').html();

        normal_price = normal_price.replace(currency_symbol,'');
        normal_price = normal_price / $('#prev_mult').val();
        var normal_price_original = normal_price;


        console.log('current before multy = '+normal_price);
        for( var i = 0; i < discount_array.length; i++ ) {
            // console.log(discount_array[i][0]);
            if ($(this).val()>=discount_array[i][0]) {
                // console.log(discount_array[i][1]);
                if (i==0) {
                    normal_price = discount_array[i][1] + (embro_chage*1)+(prev_price_1*1)+(prev_price_2*1); 
                } else {
                    normal_price = normal_price - discount_array[i][1];
                }

            }
        }
        // console.log('current after multy = '+normal_price);
        var new_price = (normal_price*$(this).val())
        $('#have_to_be_changed').html(currency_symbol+new_price.toFixed(2));
        $('#prev_mult').val($(this).val());

        // console.log(normal_price);
    }); 
    $('#have_embrodery').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
            $('#option_div_18').show();
        } else {
            // console.log('original_price - '+original_price);
            // console.log($('#prev_1').val());
            // console.log($('#prev_2').val());
            // console.log($('#prev_mult').val());
            embro_chage =0;
            var new_price_add = $('#prev_1').val()*1;
            var new_price_add_2 = $('#prev_2').val()*1;
            var new_price_mult = $('#prev_mult').val()*1;

            if (new_price_add_2) {
            } else {
                new_price_add_2 = 0;
            }


            var new_price2 = (((original_price*1)+(new_price_add*1)+(new_price_add_2*1))*(new_price_mult*1));
            // console.log('original_price  - '+original_price);
            // console.log('new_price_add   - '+new_price_add);
            // console.log('new_price_mult  - '+new_price_mult);
            // console.log('new_price2      - '+new_price2);
            $('#have_to_be_changed').html(currency_symbol+new_price2.toFixed(2));
            $('#prev_18').val('0');
            $('#option_div_18').hide();
            $('#option_18').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#prev_19').val('0');
            $('#option_div_19').hide();
            $('#option_19').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#option_32').val('');
            $('#option_div_32').hide();
            $('#option_36').val('');
            $('#option_div_36').hide()
            $('#option_37').val('');
            $('#option_div_37').hide()
            $('#option_38').val('');
            $('#option_div_38').hide()
            $('#option_32').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#option_36').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#option_37').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#option_38').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#option_33').val('');
            $('#prev_33').val('');
            $('#option_div_33').hide();
            $('#prev_34').val('');
            $('#option_34').val('');
            $('#option_div_34').hide();
            $('#prev_35').val('');
            $('#option_div_35').hide();
            $('#prev_35').val('0');
            $('#option_35').prop('selectedIndex',0);

            $('#option_div_32').hide();
            $('#option_div_33').hide();
            $('#option_div_34').hide();
            $('#option_div_36').hide();
            $('#option_div_37').hide();
            $('#option_div_38').hide();
            $('#option_32').val('');
            $('#option_33').val('');
            $('#option_37').val('');
            $('#option_34').val('');
            $('#option_36').val('');
            $('#option_38').val('');
            $('#option_32').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_33').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_34').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_36').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_37').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_38').removeClass('required');
        }
    });
    $('#option_18').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $('#option_div_19').show();
        } else {
            $('#option_div_19').hide();
            $('#option_19').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#option_div_32').hide();
            $('#option_32').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#option_div_36').hide();
            $('#option_36').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#option_div_37').hide();
            $('#option_37').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#option_div_38').hide();
            $('#option_38').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#option_div_33').hide();
            $('#option_div_34').hide();
            $('#option_div_35').hide();
            $('#option_35').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        }
    });
    $('#option_18').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $('#option_div_19').show();
            $('#font_color_info').hide();
            clearTimeout(fade_timer);
            $('#font_color_info').html('<img src="{$STORE_URL}/images/font_color/'+$("select[id=option_18] option:selected").text()+'.jpg" />');
            $('#font_color_info').show();
            fade_timer = setTimeout(function(){ $('#font_color_info').fadeOut(200); },10000);
        } else {
            $('#font_color_info').hide();
            $('#option_div_32').hide();
            $('#option_div_36').hide();
            $('#option_div_37').hide();
            $('#option_div_38').hide();
            $('#option_div_33').hide();
            $('#option_div_34').hide();
            $('#option_div_35').hide();
            $('#option_35').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            $('#option_32').val('');
            $('#option_33').val('');
            $('#option_37').val('');
            $('#option_34').val('');
            $('#option_36').val('');
            $('#option_38').val('');
            $('#option_32').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_33').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_34').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_36').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_37').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_38').removeClass('required');
        }
    });
    $('#option_19').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $('#option_div_35').show();
            $('#font_color_info').hide();
            clearTimeout(fade_timer);
            $('#font_color_info').html('<img src="{$STORE_URL}/images/font_color/'+$("select[id=option_19] option:selected").text()+'.png" />');
            $('#font_color_info').show();
            fade_timer = setTimeout(function(){ $('#font_color_info').fadeOut(200); },10000);
        } else {
            $('#option_div_32').hide();
            $('#option_div_36').hide();
            $('#option_div_37').hide();
            $('#option_div_38').hide();
            $('#option_div_33').hide();
            $('#option_div_34').hide();
            $('#option_32').val('');
            $('#option_33').val('');
            $('#option_37').val('');
            $('#option_34').val('');
            $('#option_36').val('');
            $('#option_38').val('');
            $('#option_32').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_33').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_34').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_36').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_37').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_38').removeClass('required');
        }
    });
    $('#option_35').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            //console.log ('true '+$(this).val());
            // 3782 Left Breast option_div_32
            // 3795 Right Hand Side option_div_33
            // 3796 Above Header Bar option_div_34
            // 3797 Right Hand Side & Above Header option_div_33 option_div_34
            $('#option_div_32').hide();
            $('#option_div_36').hide();
            $('#option_div_37').hide();
            $('#option_div_38').hide();
            $('#option_div_33').hide();
            $('#option_div_34').hide();
            $('#option_32').val('');
            $('#option_33').val('');
            $('#option_37').val('');
            $('#option_34').val('');
            $('#option_36').val('');
            $('#option_38').val('');
            $('#option_32').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_33').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_34').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_36').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_37').removeClass('required');
            $('#option_38').removeClass('required');
            if ($("select[id=option_35] option:selected").text()=='Left Breast') {
                $('#option_div_32').show();
                $('#option_32').addClass('required');
                $('#option_33').val('');
                $('#option_33').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_34').val('');
                $('#option_34').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_36').val('');
                $('#option_36').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_37').val('');
                $('#option_37').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_38').val('');
                $('#option_38').removeClass('required');
            }
            if ($("select[id=option_35] option:selected").text()=='Right Hand Side') {
                $('#option_div_33').show();
                $('#option_33').addClass('required');
                $('#option_32').val('');
                $('#option_32').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_34').val('');
                $('#option_34').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_36').val('');
                $('#option_36').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_37').val('');
                $('#option_37').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_38').val('');
                $('#option_38').removeClass('required');
            }
            if ($("select[id=option_35] option:selected").text()=='Centre Above Header Bar') {
                $('#option_div_34').show();
                $('#option_34').addClass('required');
                $('#option_32').val('');
                $('#option_32').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_33').val('');
                $('#option_33').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_36').val('');
                $('#option_36').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_37').val('');
                $('#option_37').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_38').val('');
                $('#option_38').removeClass('required');
            }
            if ($("select[id=option_35] option:selected").text()=='In Centre') {
                $('#option_div_37').show();
                $('#option_32').val('');
                $('#option_33').val('');
                $('#option_36').val('');
                $('#option_34').val('');
                $('#option_38').val('');
                $('#option_32').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_33').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_34').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_36').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_37').addClass('required');
                $('#option_38').removeClass('required');
            }
            if ($("select[id=option_35] option:selected").text()=='On The Back') {
                $('#option_div_36').show();
                $('#option_32').val('');
                $('#option_33').val('');
                $('#option_37').val('');
                $('#option_34').val('');
                $('#option_38').val('');
                $('#option_32').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_33').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_34').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_36').addClass('required');
                $('#option_37').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_38').removeClass('required');
            }
            if ($("select[id=option_35] option:selected").text()=='In The Header Bar') {
                $('#option_div_38').show();
                $('#option_32').val('');
                $('#option_33').val('');
                $('#option_37').val('');
                $('#option_34').val('');
                $('#option_36').val('');
                $('#option_32').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_33').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_34').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_36').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_37').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_38').addClass('required');
            }
            if ($("select[id=option_35] option:selected").text()=='Right Hand Side & Above Header Bar') {
                $('#option_div_33').show();
                $('#option_div_34').show();
                $('#option_32').val('');
                $('#option_37').val('');
                $('#option_38').val('');
                $('#option_36').val('');
                $('#option_32').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_33').addClass('required');
                $('#option_34').addClass('required');
                $('#option_36').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_37').removeClass('required');
                $('#option_38').removeClass('required');
            }
            $('#font_color_info').hide();
            clearTimeout(fade_timer);
            $('#font_color_info').html('<img src="{$STORE_URL}/images/font_color/'+$("select[id=option_35] option:selected").text()+'.png" />');
            $('#font_color_info').show();
            fade_timer = setTimeout(function(){ $('#font_color_info').fadeOut(200); },10000);
        } else {
            //console.log ('false '+$(this).val());
            $('#option_div_32').hide();
            $('#option_div_36').hide();
            $('#option_div_37').hide();
            $('#option_div_38').hide();
            $('#option_div_33').hide();
            $('#option_div_34').hide();
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#have_embrodery').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('.lets_change_the_price').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('.prev_input').val('0');
        $('#prev_mult').val('1');
        $('#option_price').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('#option_div_18').hide();
        $('#option_div_19').hide();
        $('#option_div_32').hide();
        $('#option_div_36').hide();
        $('#option_div_37').hide();
        $('#option_div_38').hide();
        $('#option_div_33').hide();
        $('#option_div_34').hide();
        $('#option_div_35').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Can't, how would the JSFiddle version of these dropdowns connect to my database to be populated.

Comment: ok, going through ur code

Comment: An update however, these "have_to_be_changed" id tags left in by another developer, I did just that and changed it to have_to_be_changed2 and seems to be helping, does anyone have an actual version of IE8 or IE9 installed to test? I am using developer tools to emulate.

Comment: Just tested by using a virtual server with IE8/IE9 installed (browserstack) and still does not work, dropdowns not appearing. In the IE developer tools it does but that's clearly not perfect to test with.

Comment: Press F12 to bring up the developer tools and press "Start debugging" on the script tab then rerun your code. Are there any errors? IE likes to silently fail unless you tell it you want to know.

Comment: Add this meta tag in between your <head> tags <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >

It will force off compatibility view. Fair warning, this is kind of a hack.

Comment: Ran it and got a number of issues relating to:
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'log'. Removed/commented out the two instances of console.log which were not already commented out and I think that's done it.

Comment: you mean now no more error. Then try the steps in below image

Comment: u got to try different things dont know which works actually many of javascript function dont work in ie like actionlistener.

Comment: i was thinking no body uses ie but strange over 55% people uses it.STRANGE

Comment: it's not strange that a large quantity of people use the browser that comes with the os.

Answer (score 0):

Ways to debug ur code

1. Press F12 to bring up the developer tools and press "Start debugging" on the script tab then rerun your code. Are there any errors? IE likes to silently fail unless you tell it you want to know.
2. Add this meta tag in between your  tags  It will force off compatibility view. Fair warning, this is kind of a hack.
3. Follow below steps in image [image: Drop Down Problem Solved]

Try this it generally works may work fine with you

Comment: Nah was not already on, one of the first things I looked for too, but what has seemed to have fixed so far is removing the last two remaining console.log instances, and would not have thought of that without your comment to run the debugger, will continue testing a little more now. If you want to add an answer relating to running the debugger I can tick that as solved.

Comment: its new people generall getting problem in ie7,8 may be ur code is wrong check o/p step by step using console.log

Comment: have u got the answer?